# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.HashMap$EntrySet.<init>()

Tags: java

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.HashMap$EntrySet.<init>()

at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2902) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2066) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
```

My JDK version is 1.7.0_80. The error message will happen again when I execute the following JUnit test code:

```
@Test
public void testGetDeclaredConstructor() throws NoSuchMethodException {
    Map<String, Object> m1 = new HashMap<>();
    Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> entrySet = m1.entrySet();

    Class clz = entrySet.getClass();

    Constructor con = clz.getDeclaredConstructor();
    con.setAccessible(true);

    System.out.println("--------Test OK!");

}
```

Comment: Why *should* there be such a constructor? What are you trying to do? `HashMap$EntrySet` is not part of any public API so any methods that it does or does not have (outside of the interfaces that it exposes) are implementation details that you should not depend on.

Comment: What is the purpose of that test scenario? Also, please be aware that `Map.Entry` is an interface. Interfaces does not have any constructors.

Comment: Thanks for your replying.You are right, EntrySet is an inner class in java.util.HashMap which owns private final mofifiers.   Why I ask this question,because I encounter such code in a colleague 's deepClone() method which throws such exception.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the answer by listing the declared constructors .

```
Set<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> entrySet = new HashMap<>().entrySet();

Constructor<?>[] declaredConstructors = entrySet.getClass().getDeclaredConstructors();
for (Constructor<?> declaredConstructor : declaredConstructors) {
    System.out.println(declaredConstructor);
}
```

> java.util.HashMap$EntrySet(java.util.HashMap)

So, there is one constructor, which takes a HashMap as argment. Hence, `getDeclaredConstructor()`, (`getDeclaredConstructor(Class<?>... parameterTypes)` with no args)  tries to get a constructor that does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on reflection but to me that sounds like there is no *default constructor* in the class of the `entrySet`. And with `getDeclaredConstructor()` that's what you're looking for.